# how does java collections saves an element (shallow or deep)

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, linked-list

In the Java collections (array, LinkedList, Set), when an object is added, does it saves a copy of the reference or copy the entire object to the collection. And if I change the original object does it effect the collection's object?

Answer (score 1):

> In the java collections (Array , LinkedList , Set) when an object is added does it saves a copy of the reference or copy the entire object to the collection.

It saves a reference.  It does not copy the object.

This can be inferred from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) for the `Collection.add` method:

> `boolean add(E e)`
>
> *Ensures that this collection contains the specified element. Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call.*

Notice that it says that the collection will contain the specified element ... not a **copy** of the specified element.

> If i change the original object does it effect the collection's object?

Yes.  They are the same object.

Comment: Note that a collection can contain itself, which is only possible with references: “[Some collection operations which perform recursive traversal of the collection may fail with an exception for self-referential instances where the collection directly or indirectly contains itself.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#:~:text=Some%20collection%20operations,contains%20itself.)” and that [mutable `Map` keys require special care](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#:~:text=great%20care,in%20the%20map.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you change the original object it does change the object inside the Collection.

You can read a similar question here which talks about java being a pass by reference: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)